# How to model many blobs for an object?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, data-modeling

I want to enable something like a one-to-many relation between a text object and blobs so that a text object (an "article" or likewise) has many images and/or videos. There are two ways I see how to do this where the first is using a list of blobs as instance variable. Will it work?

```
class A(search.SearchableModel):
  blobs = db.ListProperty(blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty())
```

Advantages: Just one class. Readable and easy to get and set data.
Disadvantages: Lacks extra info for blobs e.g. if I want to tag a blob with descriptive words I still need two classes instead:

```
class A(search.SearchableModel):
...
class B(db.Model):
  reference=db.ReferenceProperty(A,collection_name='matched_blobs',verbose_name="Title")
  blob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

The later example has a disadvantage since it requires a referenceproperty and introduces 2 classes where the problem could be solved with just class A as in the first example. The advantage of the later solution is that it's clearly documented while a listproperty of blobreferenceproperties isn't and the later solution I already have implemented and now I'm thinking about using a list of blobs instead of a referenced collection. Does it matter or will both work rather equally well? Can you recommend which way to choose, if any of these or another?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine actually has an article on this in their documentation: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! The `db.ListProperty(blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty())` I never saw in use and perhaps it won't work. I want it easy to now which blobs belongs to which entity and vice versa. I might keep the model with 2 classes here.

Comment: @Niklas It won't work - you have a list of items, not a list of properties. You want `db.ListProperty(blobstore.BlobKey)`.

Comment: `db.ListProperty(blobstore.BlobKey)` is what I was looking for. I wonder what happens in datastore admin console data view if I use the ListpRoperty instead of a reference. Now there is a clear link to "View blob" if I use my current implementation which still has traces from using the old instance variable blobproperty and I want to be able to use the `get_serving_url` so I move all blobs to blobstore and I won't use `db.BlobProperty` since blobstore is much better with get_serving_url and admin views.