# How to reference multiple Blobs from one datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to model many blobs for an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204365/how-to-model-many-blobs-for-an-object)

I have a datastore model called Location and I would like users to be able to upload a multitude of images relating to that location.  I know that I can reference those images from the Blobstore using the BlobReferenceProperty but how can I reference a lot of these properties without creating many more attributes?

Can I create a list of them or make a list property of BlobReferenceProperties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any basic datastore supported type, you can use a `ListProperty` of `BlobKey`.

```
blobRefs = db.ListProperty(blobstore.BlobKey)
```

Please note:

1. List properties retain order. This is quite useful in some situations.
2. Whole list gets serialized and stored inside the entity. There is no way to just get a part of it.
3. If property is indexed, then every entity will get it's own entry in index (or two if you index for ascending and descending). There can be a max of 5000 index entries per entity.
4. It you create a compound index with two list properties in this will lead to [exploding indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection#Exploding_Search).

Comment: Hmm so should the full property look like: List<BlobReferenceProperty> blobRefs = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

because it is telling me it can't assign to operator:Compare[left=Name[id=List, ctx=Load, reserved=false], ops=[Lt, Gt], comparators=[Name[id=BlobReferenceProperty, ctx=Load, reserved=false]

Comment: My bad. I didn't see you are using python. Updated.

Comment: alright great, thanks. i couldn't find any documentation but that works well

Answer (score 0):

If you will potentially have more than 5000 photos per location, then here is another option.

1. Create a Location entity and a Photo entity in the datastore.  The Photo entity should have a reference property to a location entity.
2. Create a datastore Photo object for each photo in the blobstore.
3. For each Photo entity, set the Location reference property to the appropriate Location object.